# How to fix too many redirects when enabling SSL for site?

Tags: redirect, ssl

I have a website which uses wordpress. It was initially uploaded and used without SSL. After installing a server certificate and adding the apache virtualhost file for the ssl site, I tried loading the https version. It loaded with a lot of warnings about insecure content being trimmed. The resulting webpage was looking ugly because a lot of css and javascript files related to the wordpress theme were not being loaded because of insecure http protocol.

I changed the .htaccess to the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://drjoel.info/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I then followed the codex instructions and changed the "Home" and "Site URL" in the mysql database to https from http. When I tried loading again, the browser kept showing "Too many redirects" error. I checked using verbosity and debug option in wget. This is what I get:

```
---request begin---
GET / HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Wget/1.19.1 (linux-gnu)
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: identity
Host: drjoel.info
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cookie: __cfduid=d700f224676946c9ea07ab3eb7cf5cb861527424630

---request end---
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 
---response begin---
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Sun, 27 May 2018 12:37:11 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://drjoel.info/
Expect-CT: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
Server: cloudflare
CF-RAY: 42188807c86caaaa-SIN

---response end---
302 Found
URI content encoding = ‘iso-8859-1’
Location: https://drjoel.info/ [following]
Skipping 204 bytes of body: [<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>302 Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Found</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="https://drjoel.info/">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>
] done.
URI content encoding = None
Converted file name 'index.html' (UTF-8) -> 'index.html' (UTF-8)
--2018-05-27 18:07:11--  https://drjoel.info/
Reusing existing connection to drjoel.info:443.
Reusing fd 3.
```

This is being repeated about 20 times before wget aborts.
What's going wrong? What is the correct technique to enable SSL for a site on Wordpress?

Answer (score 1):

Using a redirect from your web server isn't the best solution in my opinion.

Instead, why not fix directly the content of your database? (using `https://` instead of `http://` everywhere?

You could do that using a WordPress plugin such as [WP Migrate DB](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/) or the command line tool [WP-CLI](https://wp-cli.org/).

Using the plugin option (`WP Migrate DB`), in the administration go to `Tools` > `Migrate DB`.

Using the command line tool (`WP-CLI`), use the following command line: `wp search-replace http://oldurl.com https://oldurl.com`

After applying one of these two solutions, you should have a correct site that uses `https` urls instead of `http`.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Mike avoid http redirects and replace strings in files and DB.
Another useful tool for replacig strings (even serialized), -no command line- is this one: https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/